# Do I really need to reboot my host machine to restore net' connectivity to my VMware machines?

Tags: windows-7, vmware-workstation

I'm running **VMware Workstation 6.54** on a Windows 7 host (64-bit). Whenever the host loses network connectivity the VMs *never* get their connection back until I reboot the machine (which I have to do right after I finish writing this). I've tried restarting the "relevant" services (like **VMware Nat Service**) but only a hard reboot works for me. Does this issue sound familiar?

Comment: I had a similar problem, but with workstation 10. The solution that worked for me -> http://superuser.com/a/645401/111219

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had some network "goofyness" with VMware Workstation 7 on Win7x64 but haven't ever had to resort to a reboot.

At the bottom right of the client window are those little status icons. I just right-click on the network icon and select "disconnect." I wait a couple seconds and reconnect it and that seems to get the client back on track.

See if that works for you?

Comment: I'll try this when the situation happens again...

Comment: It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Been using Workstation since version 5 and never had such a problem. Recently my host PC's network cable had a problem and the connection was breaking several times a day but I never had even to refresh the guests' connections. You should look somewhere else for the source.

Some points :

Does your guests have the vmware tools installed ?

Did you update your host's network drivers (or did you update them recently causing the problem) ?

Did you play with the network service settings of Vmware Workstation ?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is if this sounds familiar, I have an answer: yes it does. I had to reboot about a dozen times per day. In my case it turned out to be a Citrix client installed on the host. Once I got rid of that, my VM never lost its connection again.

Answer (score 0):

reconnecting the network in each guest didn't work for me.  I found a solution on the vmware community site about needing to restart the vmnetbridge service.

http://communities.vmware.com/message/1081585